# ANSI C two-level include

Tags: c, makefile, include, ansi-c

I know that the title is somehow stupid but I have no idea on how to ask else.
I'm trying to include one of the standard librarys (`stdio.h` or `string.h`) in my header file (`head.h`) which is then included by my `main.c` script.

Everything works fine on my Windows 7 x64 TCC (http://bellard.org/tcc/) but the college's solaris (I have no idea but it's seriously stoneage stuff) gcc 4.0.2 (2005 apparently) just doesn't do... (I get "undefined symbol" errors etc.)

**main.c (excerpt):**

```
#include "head.h"
```

**head.h (excerpt):**

```
// include librarys
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input/output
#include <string.h>     // operations on strings
#include <locale.h>     // unicode string output
```

**makefile (complete):**

```
CX = tcc
IN = funcdef.o main.o

outfile: ${IN}
${CX} -o outfile.out ${IN}

funcdef.o: head.h funcdef.c
main.o: head.h main.c
```

What am I doing wrong? And why is GCC acting so weird when TCC isn't :D?
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Verbatim, please.

Comment: "undefined symbol" is a linker error, not a compiler one. probably has nothing to do (or not much) with `#include`s. please post whatever you are using on Solaris - what you have working with tcc is irrelevant.

Comment: It works fine for me. And don't rip on GCC. It saved my life in the Yukon.

Comment: I'm getting an "Undefined symbol _fopen" (which is one of my functions in funcdef.h) in the main.c


But when I make the program I'm getting "syntax error before or at *" where he's referencing to 
FILE *fileptr = NULL;

Comment: So simplify the code and makefile as much as you can, and add them to your post. Then maybe we'll have a chance of figuring out what the trouble is.

Comment: The symbol `_fopen` is in a system (compiler) library.  Some compilers include the standard library while others may require you to specify it on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were several syntax mistakes in the funcdef.c which lead to not linking it with the main.c.

And the syntax mistakes were mainly C++ code in ANSI C which was tolerated by tcc and hated by gcc. ^^